# What is the best way to show a popup dialog in a WebView?

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I am trying show a pop up dialog with an image inside from a webview when clicked. my problem is that the pop up dialog is not being pop up but it open full screen inside the webview or it open in a browser. is it possible to make pop up inside webview ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to make a dialog pop up from within the webview.

If you want something else to happen in your application when you do something from within the webview then things get more complicated. You probably have to roll your own framework. Netflix did this, I will try to find the link.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void mDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle("title");
    alert.setMessage("message");

    // Set an EditText view to get user input 
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    alert.setView(input);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

      }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        // Canceled.
      }
    });

    alert.show();
  }
```

This example shows a dialog with an `EditText`. I use this in a `WebView` myself.
I am sure you can config this for letting show an image